# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first - AGAIN

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, iis

I have a client running a web site portal which uses some legacy code that is periodically causing an issue. The system will work for days even weeks and then the worker process will die and no longer serve any data and you have to perform an IISRESET to get it working again

I have found numerous postings about this error and in my mind none of the solutions or explanations fit my code.

Here is the method in question that causes my error

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Data from Database using Table Name using a field list (if supplied)
    /// Otherwise will return all fields.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="TableName">The TableName rquired</param>
    /// <param name="WHERE">Where clause if required</param>
    /// <param name="FieldNames">String array of required field names (if any)</param>
    /// <returns>Dictionary List of results.</returns>
    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> Select(string TableName, string WHERE, string[] FieldNames, int TopRecords = -1, string OrderBy = null)
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        string sFieldNames = string.Empty;
        if (FieldNames.Length > 0)
        {
            sFieldNames = string.Join(", ", FieldNames);
            query = string.Format("SELECT {2}{0} FROM {1} ", sFieldNames, TableName, TopRecords > -1 ? "TOP (" + TopRecords + ") " : "");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WHERE))
            {
                query += string.Format(" WHERE {0}", WHERE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Select ALL fields
            query = string.Format("SELECT {1}* FROM {0} ", TableName, TopRecords > -1 ? "TOP (" + TopRecords + ") " : "");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WHERE))
            {
                query += string.Format(" WHERE {0}", WHERE);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrderBy))
        {
            query += " ORDER BY " + OrderBy;
        }

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "SQL : " + query );
            //Create Command
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, DBConnection))
            {
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command                    
                //Read the data and store them in the list 
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> ResultsSet = null;//Create a list to store the result
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    ResultsSet = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> ROW = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (dataReader[i].GetType().ToString() == "System.Byte[]")
                            {
                                ROW.Add(dataReader.GetName(i), (byte[])dataReader[i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ROW.Add(dataReader.GetName(i), dataReader[i] + string.Empty);
                            }
                        }
                        ResultsSet.Add(ROW);
                    }
                    dataReader.Close(); //close Data Reader
                    cmd.Dispose(); // Only added today - have to wait for some time to see if it fails
                }                  
                return ResultsSet;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Many solutions state you cannot re-use a connection to perform updates but this method does not. I am pretty sure its obvious and it is only fetching the data from the database and no updates are performed.

I don't want to use MARS unless I have absolutely no choice.

Looking for pointers as to what I might have missed

Connection string

```
<add name="APP.Properties.Settings.DB" connectionString="server=trs-app;User Id=username;password=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;database=TRailS;Pooling=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

OpenConnection Method

```
        //open connection to database
    public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {                
            if (DBConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                while (DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connecting)
                {
                    // Do Nothing
                }
                DBConnection.Open();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Connection Opened");
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    LastError = "Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator";
                    return false;
                case 1045:
                    LastError = "Invalid username/password, please try again";
                    return false;
            }
            LastError = "Unknown Error : " + ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Just spotted this in the DAL Class - is this the cause!!!

```
     private static SqlConnection DBConnection;
```

Solution might be to remove static from Sqlconnection variable (DBConnection) and implement the IDisposable pattern in the DAL class as suggested

```
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing == true)
        {
            DBConnection.Close(); // call close here to close connection
        }
    }

    ~MSSQLConnector()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

Comment: Refactoring would be great start.

Comment: I don't expect any harm if you simply new a SqlConnection wrapped in a using and use that instance instead of what comes out of DbConnection. This code might not be the problem but any other code that references that DbConnection property might not play nicely.

Comment: Please never use this method. Ever. It's an open door for SQL Injection attacks. Use stored procedures, or hard coded parameterized queries if you must, but **do not** concatenate strings with user input to create sql statements.

Comment: btw: the various `dataReader.Close()`, `cmd.Dispose()` etc that you've added: aren't needed and won't fix the problem - I do genuinely  acknowledge and appreciate that you've tried things to fix it though

Comment: @ZoharPeled - you don't know where the strings come from, the inejection risk is not clear. In general good advice though.

Comment: @user9635018 - the relevant code is not posted. But it's already too big, read about [mcve]

Comment: @HenkHolterman While your comment is correct, I think it's very likely that whenever this method get's called, it's being used with user input for at least some of it's arguments.

Comment: There is no injection possibility because this method is not having any user code supplied its all for business logic and is called by other objects , its used as a DAL for business objects.

Comment: yeah, don't put the DBConnection in a static variable. These should not be shared, create a new one for each request then close it when done. I.e. the DBConnection should ALSO be in a `using` block.

Comment: @TruAG perhaps **currently**, but I'll be willing to bet that if some new programmer would see this they might be tempted to use it. Also, your business objects must take their data from somewhere, don't they? eventually, this is just too risky IMH, especially when you have such easy ways to work with parameterized queries.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I understand your concern however this portal is only accessed buy authorized users and the data is validated before being passed to the DAL for saving. The method is called after some reflection code to build the FieldsList and Values list.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have here ... while not perfect (see Zohar's comment - it is actively dangerous, in fact), does treat the `SqlDataReader` correctly - it is making use of `using`, etc. So: if this is throwing this error, there are three possibilities:

1. of the code we *can* see, one of the operations **inside** the `while (dataReader.Read())` has *side-effects* that is causing another SQL operation to be executed on the same connection; frankly I suspect this is unlikely based on the code shown
2. there is code that we *can't* see that *already has an open reader* before this method is called

   - this could be because some code higher in the call-stack is doing another similar `while (dataReader.Read()) {...}` - typical in "N+1" scenarios
   - or it could be because something that happened *earlier* (but no-longer in the same call-stack) executed a query, and left the reader dangling
3. your `this.OpenConnection()` is sharing a connection between different call contexts without any consideration of what is going on (a textbook example of this would be a `static` connection, or a connection on some kind of "provider" that is shared between multiple call contexts)

2 and 3 are the most likely options. Unfortunately, diagnosing and fixing that requires a lot of code that *we can't see*.

Comment: I have added the OpenConnection code. 

Also ALL other methods used in the DAL class are coded with Using statements.

As I stated this is legacy and does need improving I know but there are time constraints I have no control over.
Its likely that the Openconnection should always open a new connection?

Comment: edited original question to show additional information. you mentioned static connection

Comment: @TruAG yeah, a `private static SqlConnection DBConnection;` is every kind of wrong; that means that your system scales to 1 concurrent user - as soon as you get two concurrent requests (since you mention iisreset, etc): you're doomed. Whether it should always return a *new* connection is complex; there are lots of ways of handling that. If every usage of "get connection" always uses a `using(var connection = ...)` etc, then yes: it should be new each time; but "connection per request" is also valid (as long as you close them at the end of the request)

Comment: Looks to me that the simple solution here is remove the static from the sqlconnection variable and implement IDisposable pattern in the class

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the comments and reviewing the code in light of the information provided I have refactored the DAL class to ensure every method used in the class is now set to a using statement to create the connection. I understand IIS will handle the connection pool for this

I am also closing the db connection in code too (I know its not required with a using statement but its just for neatness.

I have a small monitoring application that will periodically refresh the login page of the portal to watch for an outage and log then perform an IISReset so I can monitor if the problem goes away after all.

Thanks for all the input.

```
         //Open connection
        using (SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DBConnection.Open();
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "SQL : " + query );
            //Create Command
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, DBConnection))
            {
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command                    
                //Read the data and store them in the list 
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> ResultsSet = null;//Create a list to store the result
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    ResultsSet = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> ROW = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (dataReader[i].GetType().ToString() == "System.Byte[]")
                            {
                                ROW.Add(dataReader.GetName(i), (byte[])dataReader[i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ROW.Add(dataReader.GetName(i), dataReader[i] + string.Empty);
                            }
                        }
                        ResultsSet.Add(ROW);
                    }

                }
                DBConnection.Close();
                return ResultsSet;
            }
        }           
    }
```